# Not able to remove XOLO secure in rooted xoloq600 phone

Tags: root-access

I recently installed framaroot-1.9.3 on my xoloQ600(android 4.2.1). I selected option Boromir which was first among the 2 other options(Faramir,Barahir) on framaroot.It reported to success and I rebooted my phone then I checked from Root-Checker and It displayed that phone is rooted but when I tried to disable Xolo secure it displayed--

```
Go to Xolo secure to deactivate Device Admin.
```

My question is that why can't I remove it directly as my phone is rooted?

Answer (score 1):

That specific app called `Xolo secure` is activated as a device admin so it gets notified on specific administrator events and it has access to more, private data. If you want to disable or uninstall this application you first have to got to `Settings -> Security -> Device Admins` and then disable `Xolo secure`. After that you are free to disable or uninstall that device admin.

Note: You being unable to disable or uninstall device admins is a feature to make sure specific security related applications don't get disabled by malicious software.

Comment: its displaying the same message

Comment: Then it isn't disabled. Check if the app is ticked in the `Device admins` screen.

Comment: yes its ticked but when i try to untick it ,it asks for a 6 digit pin code which i don't know

Comment: This seems to be some weird limitation by the device manufacturer. On my device it does not ask for anything apart from confirmation. by the look of things it should be some unlock code for the security app. Deleting data may delete this, too.